# Gradle changes selected version to snapshot

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I am facing a confusing issue with gradle. I have my dependencies declared where I have a jar from my private repository. Recently I released a new version of my private lib, and when I try to import the dependency gradle automatically changes it to the SNAPSHOT version.

```
implementation group: "com.company.name", name: "my-library", version: "0.11.0"
```

and when I run the dependency tree

```
com.company.name:my-library:0.11.0 -> 0.11.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I tried forcing the version like this

```
implementation (group: "com.company.name", name: "my-library") {
 version {
     strictly '0.11.0'
 }
}
```

and still the result was

```
com.company.name:my-library:{strictly 0.11.0} -> 0.11.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I cleaned all the caches and refreshed the dependencies, I still get the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The version was set in the dependencies.lock